# Django URL Regex - Template value to View

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates

I'm having trouble passing a value from my Template `index.html` to
my View `(duplicates(request, title)`.

Restricted to version 1.4.3.

I believe it to be a regex problem on my part in the **urls.py** file.

Current Error is Page not found (404).

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^missions/$', 'app.views.index'),
  url(r'^missions/(?P<mission_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.mission_overview'),
  url(r'^missions/duplicates/(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9-\s\>]+)/$',
    'app.views.duplicates'),
)
```

I've tried using the title as a query string such as

```
url(r'^missions/duplicates/title(?P<title>[\s.\>])/$', ...)
```

**index.html**

```
{% if mt %}
  <!-- Title (string), Num (int), mission_id (list) -->
  {% for title, num, mission_id in mt%}
    {% if num > 1 %}
      <li><a href="missions/duplicates/{{ title|urlencode }}/">
        {{ title }}
      </a></li>
    {% else %}
      {% for mid in mission_id %}
        <li><a href="missions/{{mid}}/">{{title}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>No Titles</p>
{% endif%}
```

I have also tried

```
{{ request.GET.urlencode }}
```

and

```
{{% url app.views.duplicates title %}}
```

**views.py** *Only showing the required inputs*

```
def duplicates(request, title):
```

I either gotten Page not found errors or duplicates() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given).

Main goal is getting `title` from the template to the view `duplicates`.

I have some funky titles like...
`01 Wall_01-_Store>`
`AB.Chicken.1 StoreY`
`TO.Test.0 StoreZ'`
Thanks ahead of time!

**EDIT**
[image: Page not found Error]

[image: Duplicate needs 2 args error]

Comment: Do you have the ability to turn Debug on? It would be really helpful to see a real traceback.

Comment: @dylrei - Added Debug on responses.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. One conventional answer to this is to "slugify" the title and store/use that as a url/lookup key. If that's not easy, I might just make the regex broader, ex:  (?P<title>.+)

Comment: Off-hand, it looks like you are requiring "/" at the end of the URL  Try removing the part at the end: "/$" -> "$"

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to send titles as a part of the URL. You need to either pass them in as GET parameters, or store the slug of the title (as already mentioned), which would be a unique identifier (not the primary key) in the database, and send the slug as a part of the url. To pin point your issue here, you are not capturing `_`, `%`, etc as a part of the URL

Comment: @dylrei - That regex worked.  I'll look into "slugify" as I assume that is the best practice. This helped me get rolling. Appreciate the quick help!

Comment: @karthikr - Thanks for isolating the problem in this exact problem. It seems like implementing slug is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing slash was the problem here - the Page not found error shows url pattern 3 ending with a slash, but the current URL, does NOT end with a slash. I suspect some code changes between various bits copied and pasted here since the `a href=` line in the template DOES have a trailing slash.

The `TypeError` is caused by the fact that the named group is not matching anything - it requires AT LEAST ONE character, as the regex ends in `+` and not `*`. Why two trailing slashes are not needed here may also come down to code changes between bits that you've pasted up...